# Lambda expression replacement

Tags: python, lambda

In python, can the expression `lambda x: x.isFoo()` be replaced with shorter?

For example, the expression `lambda x: isFoo(x)` can be replaced just with `isFoo`

Comment: `lambda x: x.isFoo()` is already very short.

Comment: You can write static method for `x` class and use `Xclass.isFoo` instead `lambda x: x.isFoo()`. But I'm agree with @MarounMaroun.

Comment: @sheh
Kevin's answer works well, so... why static?

Comment: @sheh You don't need a special static method. The class function (as opposed to the bound method) will work just fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you could instead use `ClassName.isFoo`. Example:

```
f = lambda x: x.upper()
print f("hello")

f = str.upper
print f("hello")
```

Result:

```
HELLO
HELLO
```

Comment: It doesn't work if the attribute used was applied as an instance attribute.

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted. Something like `str.upper` is much better than the creation of a redundant lambda.

Comment: Maybe it's because the two methods aren't strictly identical. In the first one, you can pass any object that has an `upper` method. In the second one, you can pass only strings.

Answer (score 1):

```
import operator
foochecker = operator.methodcaller('isFoo')
foochecker(your_object)
```

could be the way to go.

E. g.,

```
import operator
upperify = operator.methodcaller('upper')
upperify("hello")
```

says

```
'HELLO'
```